# How can I keep the tooltip position on any screen using extjs 3.4?

Tags: extjs, position, tooltip, extjs3

I need to keep the tooltip position on any screen using extjs 3.4

Notebook Example (the right way):

[notebook screen image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oI4pN.jpg)

Monitor Example (the wrong way):

[monitor screen image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmQIE.jpg)

I want to keep the tooltip on the right side as in the first image, but if I change the page to the monitor, the tooltip changes its position

I have the tooltip in a tbar of a grid:

```
tbar :  [{
                      text: '<b>DEFINIR METAS</b>', 
                      id    : 'id_btn_definir_metas',
                      itemId: 'id_btn_definir_metas',
                      icon: '../icons/add.png',
                      scope: this,
                      scale: 'small',
                      iconAlign: 'left',
                      disabled: true,
                      handler: function(){

                            modal_ventana_definir_metas();
                            Ext.getCmp('id_textarea_observacion_metas').setValue(obs_general_de_metas);


                      }
                    },{
                      xtype: 'tbseparator', 
                    },{
                      icon: '../icons/question-frame.png',
                      itemId: 'id_btn_agregar_metas',
                      disabled : true,
                      listeners: {
                          render: function(c) {
                              new Ext.ToolTip({
                                  dismissDelay: 50000,
                                  target: c.getEl(),
                                  getTargetXY: function() {
                                    return [290,300];
                                  },
                                  html: 'Presione el botón "DEFINIR METAS" para iniciar el proceso de definición de metas.'
                              });
                          }
                      },
}],
```

Sorry by my english

Answer (score 0):

the problem was that I was specifying the position.

Of this way work perfectly:

```
tbar :  [{
                      text: '<b>DEFINIR METAS</b>', 
                      id    : 'id_btn_definir_metas',
                      itemId: 'id_btn_definir_metas',
                      icon: '../icons/add.png',
                      scope: this,
                      scale: 'small',
                      iconAlign: 'left',
                      disabled: true,
                      handler: function(){

                            modal_ventana_definir_metas();
                            Ext.getCmp('id_textarea_observacion_metas').setValue(obs_general_de_metas);


                      }
                    },{
                      xtype: 'tbseparator', 
                    },{
                      icon: '../icons/question-frame.png',
                      itemId: 'id_btn_agregar_metas',
                      disabled : true,
                      listeners: {
                          render: function(c) {
                              new Ext.ToolTip({
                                  dismissDelay: 50000,
                                  target: c.getEl(),
                                  //target: targetId,
                                  //html: 'ToolTip',
                                  anchor: 'left',
                                  //dismissDelay: 0,
                                  showDelay: 0,
                                  //autoHide: false,
                                  // getTargetXY: function() {
                                  //   return [290,300];
                                  // },
                                  html: 'Presione el botón "DEFINIR METAS" para iniciar el proceso de definición de metas.'
                              });
                          }
                      },
                    }],
```